# Какое максимальное количество элементов в массиве на C?

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0
#define pcount 520685

typedef struct node {
  int num;
  struct node* next;
} node;
void insert_end(node* list, int n) {
  node* ptr = list;
  while (ptr->next != NULL) ptr = ptr->next;
  ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
  ptr->next->num = n;
  ptr->next->next = NULL;
}
void print_list(node* list) {
  node* ptr = list;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    printf("|_%i_|-->", ptr->num, ptr->next);
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
}
void delete_p(node* p, int* count);
int main(void) {
  node* props[pcount];
  for (int i = 0; i < pcount; i++) {
    props[i] = malloc(sizeof(node));
    props[i]->num = -1;
    props[i]->next = NULL;
  }
  FILE *datain = fopen("input.txt", "r");
  int amount;
  fscanf(datain, "%i\n", &amount);
  int k[amount + 1];
  for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) k[i] = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
    fscanf(datain, "%i", k+i);
    for (int j = 0; j < k[i]; j++) {
        int p;
        if (j == k[i]-1)
            fscanf(datain, " %i\n", &p);
        else fscanf(datain, " %i", &p);
        props[p]->num == -1? props[p]->num = i : insert_end(props[p], i);
    }
  }
  FILE *dataout = fopen("output.txt", "w");
  int queries;
  fscanf(datain, "%i\n", &queries);
  for (int i = 0; i < queries; i++) {
    char act;
    int arg;
    fscanf(datain, "%c%i\n", &act, &arg);
    if (act == '-')
        delete_p(props[arg], k);
    else fprintf(dataout, "%i\n", k[arg]);
  }
  fclose(datain);
  fclose(dataout);
  for (int i = 0; i < pcount; i++) free(props[i]);
  return 0;
}
void delete_p(node* p, int* count) {
  node* ptr = p;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    count[ptr->num]--;
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
}
```

### [image: Задача]

Этот код кое-как решает задачу на картинке. Я решил сортировать свойства цифровой сортировкой, но столкнулся с проблемой. Максимальное количество элементов в массиве допустило мне только значение константы *pcount*. При больших программа просто вылетает. Объясните с чем это связано?

Comment: Плохо знаю Си, но почему Вы сначала объявляете массив с указанием размера массива, а потом динамически выделяете память?  По поводу вопроса предположу, что ограничение в кол-ве памяти.

Comment: Вы тут мешаете всё, что можно... Вы или массив делайте или список...

Answer (score 0):

Есть область памяти в стеке и в куче. Стек предназначен для временного хранения значения переменных в функциях, и иногда их количество большое. Например в рекурсивных задачах с большой глубиной *мыслей* алгоритма нужно все значения переменных хранить индивидуально для каждой глубины рекурсии.

Размер памяти для стека ограничен. Узнать размер стека ( *kbytes* ) можно так:

```
$ ulimit -s
8192
```

Большие источники информации нужно хранить в не в стеке, а в куче. С помощью `malloc`. Например массив :

```
node* props[pcount];
```

нужно хранить в куче так:

```
node * * props ;
props = ( node * * ) malloc(sizeof(node*)*pcount);
...
free (props);
```